# Is this question on helping to pick the CR of an animal companion in a homebrew class stackable?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

This question on [What CR dragon companions would make the damage output of my ranger archetype balanced?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/162164/what-cr-dragon-companions-would-make-the-damage-output-of-my-ranger-archetype-ba) seems like it may not be a good question for the stack in it's current form. But it also seem like it may.

On one hand, it seems to create a reasonable bound and a request to help fill it. But the bounds aren't explicitly laid out: equivalent damage to a Tier X Gloom Stalker and what that actually means.

On the other hand, it also seems like it's asking for help in developing a section of a homebrew class - and homebrewing for people isn't what we do here (or have done here, but maybe we can?)

The question seems to very much sit on the fence as to whether or not it's something that's fits our stack questions and I thought it would be worthwhile to talk about it on Meta to see if it is, or what can be done if it isn't.

So, is this question stackable as-is, can it be updated if it's not, or is it inherently off-topic?

Comment: To repeat my comment from the main question for the benefit of those participating in this meta: I wonder if I've padded my question out with too much context? If I strip it down to the bear bones, taking out the _why_ of my question, what I'm left with is "what Wyrmling deals the same average damage as a Tier 2 Gloom Stalker ranger?" and "what Young Dragon deals the same average damage as a late-Tier 3/early-Tier 4 Gloom Stalker ranger?", which is kinda two questions actually (not to mention the "Wyrmling but with multiattack vs. early-Tier 3 Gloom Stalker ranger", which is a third question).

Comment: If the question is changed to be more along those lines, would such questions be a better fit for the stack (and should they be asked as two/three separate questions, or are they related enough to still existing within one post)?

Comment: @NathanS Maybe supply that as answer as well? If you do go that route, I think you need to quantify the damage output for the ranger so that the potential dragons have a clear value to match.

Comment: I suppose part of the problem is, besides just stealing [Weaveworker89's numbers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/161570/35259), I'm not sure what those values should be. I'm not that confident with optimising damage output, hence my question. I know what I want flavour-wise, and I also know the dragons I originally picked are way too powerful, but I don't know how to quantify that...

Comment: @NathanS It kinda seems like you want help in realizing a goal, but you don't have a metric for that goal (yet), which makes this unclear as it stands right now.

Comment: I've gone ahead and asked a [question about ranger DPR](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/162240/35259). Even if this dragon CR question does get reopened, my new question may at least set a benchmark for the ranger damage output I want to compare against (since at the moment that's ill defined).

Comment: You might as well delete this meta question now, NautArch; I've deleted the question... in question.